# Search for question mark (?) in Azure Search

Tags: azure, search

I have a filed in an Azure Search index that contains URL's. I'm and trying to search the field for any URL's that contain a question mark (?). When I use just the question mark for the search text, no results are returned. Is it possible to search for just the question mark?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the following documentations?

- [Wildcard search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_wildcard)
- [Simple query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search)

Both states that you must excape special characters with backslash. When you do wildcard search

> You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search. No
>   text analysis is performed on wildcard search queries.

I think this will not apply if you escape them.